# Dojo ListItem with Child Inputs

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo list item that is clickable..  But at the same time we like to put input elements inside the list item.  The problem is that if you click on the child element(example checkbox)  the listitem onclick intercepts the call first(which seems opposite of the html bubble up format).  So we cannot call stoppropagation on the child element to stop the listitem from changing the page.

In the example below you will see the listitem alert come up before the checkbox alert..

How do you handle having input elements in a listitem without triggering the listitem..

fiddle::http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/HFA36/1/

ex.

```
 var list1 = registry.byId("myList");
    var item = new ListItem ({
            label: "A \"programmatic\" ListItem",
            moveTo: "#",
        noArrow:true,
            onClick : function() {
                alert("listItem clicked !" + event.target.type);
            }
        });
        list1.addChild(item);
        var check = new cb({onClick:function(){alert("checkbox clicked");event.stopPropagation();}});
        check.placeAt(item.containerNode.firstChild);
        check.startup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back and noticed that the `dojox/mobile/ListItem` is not really great when adding extra event handlers to it (checkboxes, touch gestures, ...), so to solve that I usually extend `dojox/mobile/ListItem` and fix the events by myself.

For example:

```js
var CheckedListItem = declare("dojox/mobile/CheckedListItem", [ ListItem ], {
    _initializeCheckbox: function() {
        this.checkbox = new CheckBox({

        });
        domConstruct.place(this.checkbox.domNode, this.containerNode.firstChild, "last");
        this.checkbox.startup();
        this.checkbox.onClick = this.onCheckboxClick;
    },
    onCheckboxClick: function() { },
    _setOnCheckboxClickAttr: function(handler) {
        this.onCheckboxClick = handler;
        if (this.checkbox !== null && this.checkbox !== undefined) {
            this.checkbox.onClick = handler;
        }
    },
    _onClick: function(e) {
        if (e.target !== this.checkbox.domNode) {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        }
    },
    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._initializeCheckbox();
    }
});
```

Due to overriding `_onClick()` and adding additional checks I managed to get the intended behavior.

A full example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ6Mb/